# using - instead of _ (underscore) with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm using with good results the following code to access alla of my php files into the /it directory without specifying the extension. In other words I can access to *"http://www.mydomain.com/it/about.php"* just writing *"http://www.mydomain.com/it/about"*.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/it/$1.php [L]
```

the same happen when i try to access to http://www.mydomain.com/it/question_answers.php.
How can I access directly to *"http://www.mydomain.com/it/question_answers.php"* also writing *"http://www.mydomain.com/it/question-answers"*?
I wrote the floowing code below the previous but it seems not to work.

```
Redirect 301 /question-answer http://www.mydomain.com/it/question_answer.php
```

because if i write "http://www.mydomain.com/it/question-answer" the browser try to open the page:
*"http://www.mydomain.com/it/question-answer.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php"*

A small abstract of the post:

- I have the page *"http://www.mydomain.com/it/question_answers.php"*
- with the first part of code I can get it using the link *"http://www.mydomain.com/it/question_answers"*
- I'd like to access the same page **also** with the following *"http://www.mydomain.com/it/question-answers"*

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1.php

RewriteRule it/question-answer\.php http://www.mydomain.com/it/question_answer.php [R=301,L]
```

I have changed two things: I deleted `it/` in the new URL of the first RewriteRule. Otherwise you would be redirected to `it/it/`
I also added `\.php` to the second RewriteRule. I don't really know why, but the RewriteRule seems to replace the pattern instead of redirecting. And if your pattern is `it/question-answer` and the real url is `it/questions-answer.php` the `.php` will not be replaced.